# RegionPlot with ColorFunction gives ugly frame labels

Tags: color, plotting, rasterize

I was working on a simple 2D region plot:

```
RegionPlot[x+0.45y>=122. && y>=76.8 && 83.2<=x<=101.7 && y<=88.6,{x,82,95},{y,76,90},PerformanceGoal->"Quality",ImageSize->Large,LabelStyle->16,FrameLabel->{"x","y"}]
```

Everything works as expected and gives the following result:

[image: regionplot_2d_1]

However, if I add a ColorFunction (I have tried different onces, also from reference), the whole image, including frame labels gets somehow rasterized. This looks quite ugly.

```
RegionPlot[x+0.45y>=122. && y>=76.8 && 83.2<=x<=101.7 && y<=88.6,{x,82,95},{y,76,90},ColorFunction->Function[{x, y},Norm@{x,y}],PerformanceGoal->"Quality",ImageSize->Large,LabelStyle->16,FrameLabel->{"x","y"}]
```

[image: regionplot_2d_2]

Can you reproduce it on your system? How can I use ColorFunction and RegionPlot without rasterization? Otherwise, how can I increase the resolution? RegionPlot has no ImageResolution or other similar options.

I am using **10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 9, 2014)**

Thanks a lot!

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Meanwhile, I have used

```
ContourPlot[Norm[{x, y}], {x, 82, 95}, {y, 76, 90}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 64, ContourLines -> False, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + 0.45*y >= 122. && y >= 76.8 && 83.2 <= x <= 101.7 && y <= 88.6], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 16, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotPoints -> 32]
```

as an interim solution. It produces a good looking graphics object:

[image: contourplot]

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.  I'm using version 10.0.1.0 on 64-bit Linux and the frame labels look the same in both plots for me.

Comment: No problem with v10.0.1 on a Mac OS X 10.10.1

Comment: I can confirm the issue in 10.0.1 on Win8.1 64-bit.

Comment: Still an issue in 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce what you observe in version 10.0.1 under Win7 x64: the on-screen appearance of the glyphs in tick labels and frame labels changes considerably after addition of `ColorFunction` (which introduces `VertexColors` into `Graphics` generated by `RegionPlot`). Here is the code I used to check the on-screen appearance:

```
pl1 = RegionPlot[
  x + 0.45 y >= 122. && y >= 76.8 && 83.2 <= x <= 101.7 && 
   y <= 88.6, {x, 82, 95}, {y, 76, 90}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 16, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
pl2 = RegionPlot[
  x + 0.45 y >= 122. && y >= 76.8 && 83.2 <= x <= 101.7 && 
   y <= 88.6, {x, 82, 95}, {y, 76, 90}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Norm@{x, y}], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 16, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
FlipView[{pl1, pl2}]
```

Not only the on-screen appearance changes but also `Export` to raster formats produces different results:

```
Export["pl1.png", pl1]
Export["pl2.png", pl2]
```

> [image: pl1]
>
> [image: pl2]

But when I `Export` the plots as PDFs there is no difference in the appearance of the glyphs:

```
Export["pl1.pdf", pl1]
Export["pl2.pdf", pl2]
```

I suggest you to report it to the technical support.

I also confirm that the workaround through switching to `ContourPlot` works perfectly. The key is that `Graphics` generated by `ContourPlot` does not contain `VertexColors`.

Comment: Should this be logged as a bug?

Comment: @akm It is *unexpected behavior* (the official term used by WRI) and probably should be counted as a borderline bug.